# How to change host in strongloop arc

Tags: javascript, node.js, strongloop

I need to access Strongloop arc remotly, but I can't find how to setup host to 0.0.0.0. How to change host in Strongloop arc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean you want to run `slc arc` on your server and then access it from the browser on your local machine, that should work just fine out of the box. All you need to do is put the address of the server and the dynamic port that Arc is listening on.

On your server:

```
localhost$ ssh my-server
my-server$ slc arc
Arc listening on http://127.0.0.1:14231/
..
```

Locally:

```
localhost$ open http://my-server:14321/
```

Comment: Thanks. I was running it on Codeanywhere devbox, problem was something else, all ports above 10000 weren't forwarded. Running it with PORT=4000 slc arc solved problem

Comment: StrongLoop Arc will use a different port number each time
you run it. You can provide a specific port and host number
via the environment variables PORT and HOST, for example:
 HOST=192.168.1.100 PORT=4000 slc arc